# import wp_post to another site

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Does anyone here work with wordpress?
I need to migrate a WP_POST-type data load to another site, but that site already has data, which I need to do so that there is no ID conflict on the site.

Tables:
WP_POST AND WP_POSTMETA.
Columns:
ID AND Post_ID

Thankful,

Comment: Are you aware of the export/import functions in the WP backend (Dashboard / "tools")?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should be on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, you may want to look into WP All Import/Export plugins.

Comment: I have to do this via mysql query...